# Using drop sort functions together?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

After dropping columns from my data, if I proceed to sorting the data the columns I had previously dropped reappear. How do I permanently remove them or create a new dataframe without those columns?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

gdf=gpd.read_file('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/BC_bedrock_ll83.shp')

gdf.drop(columns=['upid', 'area_m2','strat_unit', 'era','period','strat_name',
                  'gp_suite','fm_lithodm','mem_phase','rock_class','rk_char',
                  'age_max','age_min','belt','terrane','basin','basin_age',
                  'project','src_url', 'src_ref_s','map_comp','edit_date'])     
gdf.sort_values(by='gid')
```

I'm expecting to not see the columns that I have removed in the previous line but they still appear.

Basically, I am trying to remove columns (or to only select a few) so I can export back to a shapefile with less columns, what commands should I use for that?  Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `inplace` argument, `drop` is only *returning* a new dataframe (which you ignore). Use either

```
gdf.drop(columns=[...], inplace=True)
```

or

```
gdf = gdf.drop(columns=[...])
```